# How do I build a shared library using Go that calls an .net function?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, go, visual-studio-code

I am trying to call the function `TestSay` in the shared library `test.so`, but am getting the error `Unable to find an entry point named 'TestSay' in shared library 'test.so'`

[image: code sample]

I operate it on Linux, then meet this problem. but the `*.so` library calls an C function, it works.

so,I hope it can run success on an .net function .
[image: .Net addressing]

my codes:
test.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "C"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
}

//export TestSay
func TestSay() {
    fmt.Println("Hello go ....")
}
```

main.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main()
{
    // 加载动态库
    void *handle = dlopen("./test.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle)
    {
        printf("无法加载动态库: %s\n", dlerror());
        return 1;
    }

    // 获取函数指针
    typedef int (*AddFunc)();
    AddFunc testSay = (AddFunc)dlsym(handle, "TestSay");
    if (!testSay)
    {
        printf("无法获取函数指针: %s\n", dlerror());
        dlclose(handle);
        return 1;
    }

    // 调用函数
    // int result = add(2, 3);
    // printf("结果: %d\n", result);
    testSay();
    // 卸载动态库
    dlclose(handle);

    return 0;
}
```

run it
[image: calls an c function]
.net codes

```
using System.Reflection.Metadata;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace hello_web
{
    public class Test
    {
        [DllImport("test.so", EntryPoint = "TestSay")]
        public static extern void TestSay();

        public static void GetTestAdd()
        {
            TestSay();
        }
    }
}
```

I work on ubuntu 22.04
[image: platform]

Comment: I promise the method is exist.

Comment: Exactly how many programming languages are mixed into this question?